Can't connect slider revolution with Facebook: API error: error optaining page data access token
I am trying to create a slider for the feed of a Facebook page with slider revolution. When I try to link the Facebook account to the slider I get this error: "Facebook API error: error getting access token for page data", while the Instagram account bound to that page works.
I have also tried to create the token manually from developper.facebook.com with API Graph and inserted the token into the slider, but I get this other error: Make sure that the stream settings are prorerly selected in Module General options > Content > Stream Settings
In the API Graph tool in the me/accounts endpoint I get this result:
{
  "data": [
    {
      "access_token": "my token",
      "category": "Organization",
      "category_list": [
        {
          "id": "my ID",
          "name": "My organization"
        }
      ],
      "name": "My Page name",
      "id": "page ID",
      "tasks": [
        "ADVERTISE",
        "ANALYZE",
        "CREATE_CONTENT",
        "MESSAGING",
        "MODERATE",
        "MANAGE"
      ]
    }
  ],
  "paging": {
    "cursors": {
      "before": "QVFIUmQ3bVNJT05ZATVREaFp3ejRRRzdreHg5Q3pnV0xXbFFmWXk2ZAUo3Mm9lZADhTN0c5YnF2QTBienJKWG1tZAy0tXzhRZA0lhUGEzcVVzVkhNcTRzQ3I1R0N3",
      "after": "QVFIUmQ3bVNJT05ZATVREaFp3ejRRRzdreHg5Q3pnV0xXbFFmWXk2ZAUo3Mm9lZADhTN0c5YnF2QTBienJKWG1tZAy0tXzhRZA0lhUGEzcVVzVkhNcTRzQ3I1R0N3"
    }
  }
}

In WordPress I disabled all the plugins and custom theme, but still have error. What could be the problem?
Thank you any help
